# Best way to handle dynamic table value parsing in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

Im sure this has been come across pretty often but all of the resources I can find detail ways to handle this as an individual situation and require a manipulation strategy that lacks scalability.

Problem:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of modalConfig.tableData">
  <td> {{row.title}}</td>
  <td> {{row.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

The real problem here is that some of this data needs to be piped and others do not. I can manipulate this in the page model but id rather understand a strategy for handling this.

Is the best practice to manipulate this passed in data then display the manipulated data? is there a way to, for instance if two of the 8 values are dates, display them in a formatted way without manipulating the data in the array?

Ideally I would like to separate the data and view in this instance rather than change the source data then display it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Pipes are useful for filtering dynamic data and transforming values, but IMHO you'll be better off transforming your data values before they get to the `*ngFor`

Comment: @Kinglish I hear you its hard to know the best way, but as the answer points out my issue is that transforming the data before you present it causes a mutability issue where in an enterprise system changing the data could cause issues later if another service gets added that also changes the data or expects it to look a certain way, and if i duplicate and change it, then i have to revert it to its original form to send back after transforming it. I was hoping there was a clean no over head solution but it looks like a custom pipe is the cleanest way, just changing the data that is presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m of the opinion that the data has to be transformed for the display no matter where you do it. That in itself makes it less maintainable if the data structure or the displayed table changes.

You could waste a lot of time making some generic transformation engine but that would take a lot of effort and wouldn’t handle edge cases very well. That leaves us making changes to the underlying data OR updating the view.

I’m almost always going to say keep the data in the original shape you need, so you can easily make edits and post it back to the server if need be. That leaves us with pipes. This is my preferred method. It is the most simple and in my opinion most elegan. It is easy to understand, customizable, performant (memoization), and leaves the underlying data in tact.

Comment: so custom pipes with conditions is the way to go?

Comment: That’s what I’ve found easiest to implement and maintain.